# Deleting a video from a playlist with YouTube Data API v3 in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube, youtube-api, syntax-error

**Question**: How to use [delete](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/delete) of playlistItems in Google Apps Script?

---

**What I tried:**

1. All these give
   `Missing name after . operator. (line 123, file "Code")` error (I have a sense it might be related to JavaScript [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator, not sure.):

`YouTube.PlaylistItems.delete()`
`YouTube.PlaylistItems.delete("PLi22jkbHFzDjQNWcy4qfLamNjyb0nvkq8")`
`YouTube.PlaylistItems.delete({id: "PLi22jkbHFzDjQNWcy4qfLamNjyb0nvkq8"})`

2. Apparently, executes fine, but no effect:

```
  var payload =
      {
        "id" : "PLi22jkbHFzDjQNWcy4qfLamNjyb0nvkq8",
      };

  var options =
      {
        "method" : "delete",
        "payload" : payload
      };

  Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", options));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Extra details.** The thing I want to do is clear all of the items in a playlist and I already have the following code:

```
  var result = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('id', {
    playlistId: "2L1YG9ktx9sVdo-PMFD2iwCC-UWmkYrgQ-"
  });

  Logger.log(result.items.length);

  var items = result.items;

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(items[i].id);
    // Deletion of the item with id of "items[i].id is expected to happen here
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the videoId, you use the id of the playlistItem...

```
while (nextPageToken != null) {

  var playlistResponse = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet', {playlistId: playlistId, maxResults: 50,pageToken: nextPageToken});

  for (var j = 0; j < playlistResponse.items.length; j++) {
    var playlistItem = playlistResponse.items[j];
    playlistItemsDelete(playlistItem.id)
    //Logger.log('[%s] Title: %s', playlistItem.snippet.resourceId.videoId,  playlistItem.snippet.title);
  }
```

...And then...

function playlistItemsDelete(id) {
  //var params = {'onBehalfOfContentOwner': 'everythingability'}; // See full sample for function

YouTube.PlaylistItems.remove(id)

}

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not delete() in Apps script. Try `YouTube.PlaylistItems.remove(id)` instead. I tried adding this method in my script and it automatically populated remove method in the dropdown. There is no delete method.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for answering.

`remove()` seems plausible, although throws `ReferenceError: "Youtube" is not defined.`. I didn't manage to find anything about it in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/delete), so maybe there is no method at all for this function in the Youtube API for Google Apps Script.

By the way, how to open the dropdown?:D Seems immensely useful

Comment: maybe should be "YouTube" but i am getting a similar error with it spelled either way...you figure this out?